# Is it possible to stop execution in codemirror (timeout)?

Tags: python, codemirror

If a user just creates an infinite loop it seems it is a bit tricky to abort the execution. Is there a way to set a maximum time for execution?

Comment: How is codemirror (a JavaScript library) related to Python and how is all that related to code execution? Codemirror is just an editor.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I thought Codemirror executed the code as well.